# WiFi keeps dropping and won't connect

Tags: wifi

I have elementary OS Freya 0.3.1 Installed on my HP Pavilion G6 2014TX laptop.

My college WiFi connection connects at first but it keeps on dropping after 2-5 mins and doesn't connect after that.

My college uses **wpa2 enterprise** connection. I have **Ralink** **RT5390** WiFi card.

I have already tried disconnecting and reconnecting.

Comment: Please do not use an ALL-CAPS title.

Comment: I would check these to see if there's something helpful: http://askubuntu.com/questions/574211/wifi-keeps-dropping-out-but-stills-says-im-connected, http://askubuntu.com/questions/604582/wifi-keeps-dropping-connection, http://askubuntu.com/questions/529347/how-do-i-keep-my-wifi-from-dropping-out